# blogdown::serve_site() times out and live preview in viewer does not load

Tags: r, blogdown

I have made a site using blogdown but never got around to deploying it. I haven't touched my site for maybe a month and half but the live preview was working at that time. I could see a preview of my site in the Viewer tab.

Today, I opened my project and blogdown initiated the live preview on startup. However, I got the following error:

```
ERROR: The process "2848" not found.
Error: It took more than 30 seconds to launch the server. There may be something wrong. The process has been killed. If the site needs more time to be built and launched, set options(blogdown.server.timeout) to a larger value.
```

I restarted R and my device. I updated R, Rstudio and all of my packages. I still get an error but the process number changes every time I open the project or run `blogdown::serve_site().`

I thought that maybe my site is taking too long to load because it's too large even though it only has a few posts so far. So, I tried creating a new test site using the default Hugo theme and it started up as expected with the preview. However, if I try to change the Hugo theme using `install_theme()` I've run into this same error message.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5      bookdown_0.21   ps_1.4.0        digest_0.6.27  
 [5] later_1.1.0.1   R6_2.5.0        jsonlite_1.7.1  magrittr_1.5   
 [9] evaluate_0.14   blogdown_0.21   rlang_0.4.8     promises_1.1.1 
[13] rstudioapi_0.11 rmarkdown_2.5   tools_4.0.3     servr_0.20     
[17] processx_3.4.4  httpuv_1.5.4    xfun_0.18       yaml_2.2.1     
[21] compiler_4.0.3  htmltools_0.5.0 knitr_1.30
```

**Update 10/30: Issue resolved**

As suggested in the comments, I ran `blogdown::build_site` which gave me different errors. I fixed the first one about a bad request. I am not able to reproduce the error now but the fix was to add `ignoreErrors =["error-remote-getjson"]` to my config.toml file

Comment: FYI this issue [has been fixed in the dev version of **blogdown**](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/32349667206b5e00b610c0ec913456aab4812439).

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide a reproducible example, my current guess is that you run into a **blogdown** bug that [I have fixed two weeks ago](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/ab410b7a7ea3a6addd246f67b391b4bb9f18ae43). Please try the current development version:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

Remember to restart R.

Comment: I tried this, but I got a similar error about the server taking more than 5 seconds. Not sure how to provide a reproducible example, since it occurs on start up. Here are the steps I take:
1. Open R
2. Open project
3. ```blogdown:::preview_site(startup = TRUE``` automatically runs in the console

Comment: Where do I set options for blogdown? The error suggests changing options(blogdown.server.timeout) to a greater value.

Comment: You can set the option in the file `.Rprofile`. However, I doubt if it will help. Try to run `blogdown::build_site()` and see if it tells you more information.

Comment: Thank you! I ran ```blogdown::build_site()``` which gave me a Bad Request error which I was able to fix.

Comment: @YihuiXie I face the exact same problem as described above. I tried the steps you suggested above. When I run blogdown::build_site(), it goes smoothly without any problem. Though, I can't preview my website.

Comment: @Y_gr Could you please provide a reproducible example? You may file an issue to https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues with the reproducible example (such as a Github repo). Thanks!